# sp_addserver - Where does it add in which system table

Tags: sql-server-2008

sp_addserver - Where does it add in which system table. if I use this in my current server configuration will it change the name of my server and how will it affect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sp_addserver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174411.aspx) is for adding servers - for anything other than the local server, it is adding a linked server. It puts server information in the catalog view (*not* system table) [`sys.servers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178530.aspx). It does not affect the name of your current server unless you are actually using it to run `sp_dropserver` / `sp_addserver` after you have already renamed the underlying server (which you do to ensure functions like `@@SERVERNAME` return the right value) - this should be a rare incident.